# What is the definition of sati (chaste women) as per scriptures?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, smriti, sati

In the light of scriptures, What is the definition of sati or a chaste women? Does it mean a women who never held sexual relationship throughout her life except with her husband post marriage **OR** Is it someone who maintains a committed monogamous relationship after the marriage but has experienced pre-marital past exposures ?

PS : The question doesn't refer to Devi sati or the sati practice of past.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, when there's doubt on Skt meanings, it's best to check Saṁskṛtakośas.
Halāyudha's Abhidhānaratnamālā ([2.340](https://archive.org/details/b30092875/page/52/mode/2up?view=theater)) gives the following meanings/synonyms of satī - 
 kulabālikā, kulastrī, pativratā, sucaritā, and sādhvī. 
Amarasiṁha's Amarakośaḥ ([2.2.6](https://archive.org/details/AmaraKoshaSatyadevaMisra/page/n175/mode/2up?view=theater)) gives these meanings/synonyms of satī - sucaritrā, sādhvī, pativratā.
These two kośas describe *satī* most elaborately, Śabdakalpadruma, Abhidhānacintāmaṇi, etc. don't cover such a  wide range of synonyms/meanings.
Since, *satī* is pativratā, she would be devoted to her pati for her life after vivāha. Pre-marital intercourse is niṣiddha, as per śāstras. Cases like Kuntī, Satyavatī, etc. are exceptions, because their saṁyoga happened with devatā or Ṛṣi and they weren't defiled by this saṁyoga, they remained akṣatyoni kanyās before their vivāha. Here, Gāndharva vivāha is not included in pre-marital intercourse as the two parties undergoing it, become pati-patnī.
Also, a *satī* might not necessarily be a patnī, she might be a saṁnyāsinī (sādhvī) too, as per the meanings given above.